# .template.dart file not being created

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I'm trying to make the Routes class working.
When I try to import

`import 'package:mango/src/component/pages/dashboard_component.template.dart' as dashboard_template;`

I get this error:

```
[SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart:
Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
generated file).

Please check the following imports:

`import 'src/component/pages/dashboard_component.template.dart' as _ref3;` from mango|lib/app_component.template.dart at 19:1
`import 'package:mango/lib/src/component/pages/dashboard_component.template.dart' as dashboard_template;` from mango|lib/src/routes.template.dart at 9:1
`import 'package:mango/lib/src/component/pages/dashboard_component.template.dart' as dashboard_template;` from mango|lib/src/routes.dart at 5:1
```

And looking at the build directory structure I noticed that the dashboard_component.template.dart hasn't been created while all the others are.

lib/src/routes.dart

```
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';
import 'package:mango/src/component/pages/dashboard_component.template.dart' as dashboard_template;
import 'route_paths.dart';
export 'route_paths.dart';

class Routes {
    static final dashboard = RouteDefinition(
        routePath: RoutePaths.dashboard,
        component: dashboard_template.DashboardComponentNgFactory,
        useAsDefault: true,
    );

    static final all = <RouteDefinition>[
        dashboard,
    ];
}
```

lib/src/component/pages/dashboard_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import '../customers/customers_component.dart';
import '../customers/new_customer_component.dart';
import '../../data_service.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard_component.html',
  providers: [
    CustomersComponent,
    NewCustomerComponent,
  ],
)
class DashboardComponent {
  final DataService _dataService;

  DashboardComponent(this._dataService);
}
```

lib/app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'src/component/header/header_component.dart';
import 'src/component/pages/dashboard_component.dart';
import 'src/model/customer.dart';
import 'src/data_service.dart';
import 'src/routes.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: "app_component.html",
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  directives: [
    coreDirectives,
    routerDirectives,
    HeaderComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
  ],
  providers: [ClassProvider(DataService)],
  exports: [RoutePaths, Routes],
)
class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  final DataService dataService;

  List<Customer> get customers => dataService.customers;

  AppComponent(this.dataService);

  @override
  ngOnInit() {
    dataService.init();
  }
}
```

I searched other threads but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: it seems that you have an error in `dashboard_component.html`, can you post it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  there  are  errors in your .html  Therefore  the template is  not  getting generated in .dart_tools/build/generated

Delete .dart_tools/build   folder.  Then  on the command  line   execute -

```
 pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

This should show  some  errors.  If  not, you have  to  manually check  the  syntax in  html  file

Also check if all the correct  directives and  providers  are  listed in the .dart  file

Comment: Thanks, running that command showed me a better description of the error. The template was not created due to a missing Directive in the DashboardComponent.